# Object, mesh, material, material slot, face, material assignment: How do they work all together?

Tags: materials

I've had a hard time to figure out why I couldn't set a different material for a given face on a mesh used by two objects (duplicate by <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>).

As soon as I was assigning a material to a face on one object, the face was also changed on the other object, in spite the material was 'object-linked'.

[image]

I initially set the material slots exactly the same for the two objects, including materials used by both objects. What I realized (and the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/materials/assigning_a_material.html) doesn't help) is that one doesn't assign a *material* to a face, one rather assign the *material slot*. This slight difference has indeed a lot of consequences.

The solution was to set different materials to the same slot in each object and not changing the material-face assignment.

---

Slots have a taste of [C pointers](https://www.cprogramming.com/debugging/segfaults.html) for the mass... whatever, this leaves me with more questions:

- Is that correct the slots are the actual entities which have the 'storage location' attribute and are stored either at mesh ('data') level or at 'object' level?
- Is that correct slots (not materials) are assigned to faces, and in the case of object duplicates sharing the same mesh, the face-slot assignment done with the 'Assign' button is shared between duplicates?
- Is it true that a face is assigned by reference to the absolute position of a slot in the list? The evidence is using the up/down arrow of the slot list in the Material tab, to change the order materials appear, actually changes which material is assigned to a face .

That's the general idea, do I miss an important point regarding the use of the material slots? Any reference to good documentation to go further appreciated, especially a description of the model.

Comment: When you look at the mesh name you see the number 2.  2 users means sharing.

Comment: A face has  an integer  material index property..  Will be the active material slot index when set from UI.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75816/how-to-distinguish-material-and-material-slot/

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos: Your answer to the linked question would be valid here too. Very educative.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

---

Questions

- Q1. Slots can be stored at Object or Mesh level to suit your needs.
- Q2. Slots color faces. Slots at the Mesh Data level can be shared.
- Q3. I do not believe your statement is true in all cases. I reordered slots and did not see same result as stated in your question.
- Your probably know this. You can switch to shared data by choosing the existing data item.  You can stop sharing by clicking on the number which is greater than 1 in the mesh data panel, seen in the image below.  The image above shows Duplicate and Duplicate Linked.  The User Preferences can also fine tune these settings.  A Blender Material contains a sequence of slots which can be assigned to faces.

[image]