# Added material - now it's covering several parts of my model, how do I stop that happening?

Tags: texturing, materials

Applied texture to one object, added nodes, came out nice, however the photo/texture from that object is also on several other parts of my model, and I don't know how I have achieved that.

Perhaps I have the model linked, but being new, I am not sure of the differences yet between linked, joined, or parents and children etc. What have I done wrong and how do I fix it?

I have tried to unlink the model (if that's the problem that's causing the texture to appear over other parts not wanted), by going to object relations, make single user. However, that doesn't seem to have worked.   TIA

Comment: You can add multiple material slots to an object and assign different parts to them in edit mode. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/materials/assignment.html

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75816/how-to-distinguish-material-and-material-slot/75820#75820