# Shader does not work, no matter what nodes I use, nothing happens to the subject, and I have "Use Nodes" enabled

Tags: node-editor, shaders

I use Blender shading and nothing works on the object.... no nodes, nothing. I have checked all prior basic settings, clicked the *Use Nodes* option, still nothing works.

[image]

Comment: Hello. A screenshot of your whole interface would help a lot here. Cheers

Comment: Or even share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: This should help you https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75816/how-to-distinguish-material-and-material-slot and this of course: https://youtu.be/1qSTcxt2t74?t=1319

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What you show in the viewport is exactly the result I'd expect from the shown node tree

Comment: it looks like you have 2 materials on your object, and you are editing the second material. Are you sure that the second one is the one that is applied to your object? It is tough to judge as they both appear to be a similar colour, but by default it would assign the 1st material. (you can go into edit mode and assign the materials to selected poly's from there.)

Comment: @McBrett this is an answer. Please post it as such.