# Shaders and Texturing

Tags: texturing, shaders

I learning Blender. I have understood some basics in modeling and trying to understand how to work with materials.

Can anyone give me examples when is it better to use Shaders and when is it better to use Texturing?

I'm trying to distinguish the difference in these two approaches.

Comment: I guess you mean when it is better to use image textures in a material instead of staying 100% procedural? I guess most of the time people use image textures when procedural can't do the trick

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139621/blender-2-8-do-materials-always-have-textures/139649#139649 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75816/how-to-distinguish-material-and-material-slot/75820#75820

Comment: Thank you for the links!