# How exactly do you color models?

Tags: texture-painting

As my understanding goes there are 3 ways to color a model:

-Download another software for that

-Download photoshop/gimp/paint and color the unwrapped version of your model

-Use the blender brushes

but I don't know what are the other softwares to download, I don't know how to color something that was unwrapped... any link for tutorials out ther? cause I can't find any.

I tried the blender brushes and they are very limited.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75816/how-to-distinguish-material-and-material-slot/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72811/materials-textures-and-how-they-relate-to-models-before-after-render