Copying a material from one Blender file to another
I have a material in a Blender file that I would like to be able to use in another Blender file that I am currently working on. I have seen instructions that say to append the material by going into file → append → name of file → textures and then selecting the texture although the folder appears to be empty despite the texture being used in the file.
I am running Blender 4.0.2 if this makes a difference.

File → append → name of file → textures appends, as the name says textures. Did you try the specific category for Materials? See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72811/materials-textures-and-how-they-relate-to-models-before-after-render/72818#72818

I have just tried doing that and it has now worked.

I have now solved the problem by using File File → append → name of file → materials instead of file → append → name of file → textures.
